# Inconsistent results while web scraping using beautiful soup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am having an inconsistent issue that is driving me crazy. I am trying to scrape data about rental units. Let's say we have a webpage with 42 ads, the code works just fine for only 19 ads then it returns:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 53, in <module>
    title = real_state_title.div.h1.text.strip()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'div'
```

If you started the code to process ads starting from a different ad number, let's say 5, it will also process the first 19 ads then raises the same error!

Here is a minimum code to show the issue I am having. Please note that this code will print the HTML for a functioning ad and also for the one with the error. What is printed is so different.

Run the code then change the value of `i` to see the results.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup  # HTML data structure
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq  # Web client
import traceback


page_url = "https://www.kijiji.ca/b-apartments-condos/saint-john/c37l80017?ll=45.273315%2C-66.063308&address=Saint+John%2C+NB&ad=offering&radius=20.0"

# opens the connection and downloads html page from url
uClient = uReq(page_url)

# parses html into a soup data structure to traverse html
page_soup = soup(uClient.read(), "html.parser")
uClient.close()

# finds each ad from Kijiji web page
containers = page_soup.findAll('div', {'class': 'clearfix'})

# Print the number of ads in this web page
print(f'Number of ads in this web page is {len(containers)}')

print_functioning_ad = True

# Loop throw ads
i = 1  # change to start from a different ad (don't put zero)

for container in containers[i:]:
    print(f'Ad No.: {i}\n')
    i += 1

    # Get the link for this specific ad
    ad_link_container = container.find('div', {'class': 'title'})
    ad_link = 'https://kijiji.ca' + ad_link_container.a['href']
    print(ad_link)

    single_ad = uReq(ad_link)

    # parses html into a soup data structure to traverse html
    page_soup2 = soup(single_ad.read(), "html.parser")
    single_ad.close()

    # Title
    real_state_title = page_soup2.find('div', {'class': 'realEstateTitle-1440881021'})

    # Print one functioning ad html
    if print_functioning_ad:
        print_functioning_ad = False
        print(page_soup2)

    print('real state title type', type(real_state_title))

    try:
        title = real_state_title.div.h1.text.strip()
        print(title)
    except Exception:
        print(traceback.format_exc())
        print(page_soup2)
        break

    print('____________________________________________________________')
```

**Edit 1:**

In my simple example I want to loop through each ad in the provided link, open it, and get the title. In my actual code I am not only getting the title but also every other info about the ad. So I need to load the data from the link associated with every ad. My code actually does that, but for an unknown reason, this happens ONLY for 19 ads regardless which one I started with. This is driving my nuts!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured out the problem here. I seems like you can't make a lot of requests in a short period of time, so I added a `try: except:` statement where a time sleep of 80 second is issued when this error occurs, this fixed my problem!

You may want to change the sleep time period to a different value depends on the website you are trying to scrape from.

Here is the modified code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup  # HTML data structure
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq  # Web client
import traceback
import time


page_url = "https://www.kijiji.ca/b-apartments-condos/saint-john/c37l80017?ll=45.273315%2C-66.063308&address=Saint+John%2C+NB&ad=offering&radius=20.0"

# opens the connection and downloads html page from url
uClient = uReq(page_url)

# parses html into a soup data structure to traverse html
page_soup = soup(uClient.read(), "html.parser")
uClient.close()

# finds each ad from Kijiji web page
containers = page_soup.findAll('div', {'class': 'clearfix'})

# Print the number of ads in this web page
print(f'Number of ads in this web page is {len(containers)}')

print_functioning_ad = True

# Loop throw ads
i = 1  # change to start from a different ad (don't put zero)

for container in containers[i:]:
    print(f'Ad No.: {i}\n')
    i = i + 1

    # Get the link for this specific ad
    ad_link_container = container.find('div', {'class': 'title'})
    ad_link = 'https://kijiji.ca' + ad_link_container.a['href']
    print(ad_link)

    single_ad = uReq(ad_link)

    # parses html into a soup data structure to traverse html
    page_soup2 = soup(single_ad.read(), "html.parser")
    single_ad.close()

    # Title
    real_state_title = page_soup2.find('div', {'class': 'realEstateTitle-1440881021'})
    try:
        title = real_state_title.div.h1.text.strip()
        print(title)
    except AttributeError:
        print(traceback.format_exc())
        i = i - 1
        t = 80
        print(f'----------------------------Sleep for {t} seconds!')
        time.sleep(t)
        continue

    print('____________________________________________________________')
```

Answer (score 0):

To get all pages from the URL you can use next example:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


page_url = "https://www.kijiji.ca/b-apartments-condos/saint-john/c37l80017?ll=45.273315%2C-66.063308&address=Saint+John%2C+NB&ad=offering&radius=20.0"

page = 1
while True:
    print("Page {}...".format(page))
    print("-" * 80)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(page_url).content, "html.parser")

    for i, a in enumerate(soup.select("a.title"), 1):
        print(i, a.get_text(strip=True))

    next_url = soup.select_one('a[title="Next"]')
    if not next_url:
        break

    print()

    page += 1
    page_url = "https://www.kijiji.ca" + next_url["href"]
```

Prints:

```
Page 1...
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1 Spacious One Bedroom Apartment
2 3 Bedroom Quispamsis
3 Uptown-two-bedroom apartment for rent - all-inclusive
4 New Construction!! Large 2 Bedroom Executive Apt
5 LARGE 1 BEDROOM UPTOWN $850 HEAT INCLUDED AVAIABLE JULY 1
6 84 Wright St Apt 2
7 310 Woodward Ave (Brentwood Tower) Condo #1502

...

Page 5...
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1 U02 - CHFR - Cozy 1 Bedroom + Den - WEST SAINT JOHN
2 2+ Bedroom Historic Renovated Stainless Kitchen
3 2 Bedroom Apartment - 343 Prince Street West
4 2 Bedroom 5th Floor Loft Apartment in South End Saint John
5 Bay of Fundy view from luxury 5th floor 1 bedroom + den suite
6 Suites of The Atlantic - Renting for Fall 2021: 2 bedrooms
7 WOODWARD GARDENS//2 BR/$945 + LIGHTS//MAY//MILLIDGEVILLE//JULY
8 HEATED & SMOKE FREE - Bach & 1Bd Apt - 50% off 1st month's rent
9 Beautiful 2 bedroom apartment in Millidgeville
10 Spacious 2 bedroom in Uptown Saint John
11 3 bedroom apartment at Millidge Ave close to university ave
12 Big Beautiful 3 bedroom apt. in King Square
13 NEWER HARBOURVIEW SUITES UNFURNISHED OR FURNISHED /BLUE ROCK
14 Rented
15 Completely Renovated - 1 Bedroom Condo w/ small den Brentwood
16 1+1 Bedroom Apartment for rent for 2 persons
17 3 large bedroom apt. in King Street East Saint John,NB
18 Looking for a house
19 Harbour View 2 Bedroom Apartment
20 Newer Harbourview suites unfurnished or furnished /Blue Rock Ct
21 LOVELY 2 BEDROOM APARTMENT FOR LEASE 5 WOODHOLLOW PARK EAST SJ
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Andrej! In my simple example I want to loop through each ad in the provided link, open it, and get the title. In my actual code I not only getting the title but also every other info about the ad. So I need to load the link associated with every ad.

My code actually does that, but for an unknown reason, this happens ONLY for 19 ads regardless which one I started with. This is driving my nuts!